# Skype won't install in ubuntu 12.10

Tags: installation, 12.10, skype

Skype will not fully install because "Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 skype : Depends: skype-bin
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Obviously, I don't understand the basic gibberish of ubuntu, can anyone suggest what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the package completely with the following:

```
sudo apt-get purge skype-bin
```

Then [go here](http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-linux/downloading/?type=ubuntu64), but instead of downloading Skype, open it with Ubuntu Software Center. Install it from there and accept any warnings. That should take care of dependencies for you. If it fails again - comment here with details.